# Proving by using intersection construction that language is regular

Tags: regular-language

L is a regular language and Σ is the alphabet . Proof using intersection construction that L' is a regular language.

[two muppets http://imageshack.com/a/img661/4318/T38eP9.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/4318/T38eP9.png)

which languages I should intersect?

Comment: Why do you want to use intersection? And what did you try yourself?

Comment: 1- The lecturer wants in this way
2- I have no idea which languages I should intersect.

Comment: Could you ask your lecturer for a hint? I know how to solve your question, but the intersection construction is not the main ingredient of my solution.